# Envio/Upload de imagens com php

Tags: php

Form

```
<label>Imagem do produto:</label>
<input type="file" name="imagem-produto">
```

Script

```
$foto = $_POST["imagem-produto"];
$tamanhoMax = 1024 * 1024; # 1MB

if (isset($_FILES['imagem-produto']['name']) && $_FILES['imagem-produto']['error'] == 0):
    if ($_FILES['imagem-produto']['size'] < $tamanhoMax):
        $arquivoTMP = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
        $nomeF = $_FILES["imagem-produto"]["name"];
        //Seleciona extensão
        $extensaoF = pathinfo($nomeF, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //Converte a extensão para minúsculo
        $extensaoF =  strtolower($extensaoF);
        //Somente imagens .jpg;.jpeg;.png
        if (strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.png', $extensaoF)):
            //nome único para a imagem
            //Evita nomes com acentos ou caracteres alfanuméricos
            $novoNomeF = uniqid(time()).$extensaoF;
            //Concatena a pasta com o nome
            $destino = 'imagens_produtos/' . $novoNomeF;
            if (@move_uploaded_file($arquivoTMP, $destino)):
?>
                <p class="alert success">Sua foto foi cadastrada com sucesso.</p>
<?php
            ;else:
?>
            <p class="alert error">Erro ao salvar arquivo, aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita</p>
<?php
            endif;
        ;else:
?>
        <p class="alert error">Só aceitamos arquivos com as extensões <span>.jpg</span>, <span>.png</span> ou <span>.jpeg</span> .</p>
<?php
        endif;
    ;else:
?>
        <p class="alert error">O arquivo de imagem ultrapassa o limite de peso. <span>(0.5MB)</span></p>
<?php
    endif;
;else:
?>
    <p class="alert error">Você não enviou nenhum arquivo.</p>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Realizei este script para gravar imagens no servidor, porém fica sempre entrando no primeiro erro. Como resolver ? Há algum outro problema no código ?

*Primeiro erro = primeira condição `else` (`<p class="alert error">Você não enviou nenhum arquivo.</p>`)

Comment: colocou o `enctype` no `<form>` ?

Comment: sim, coloquei, e mesmo assim ele gerava o erro

Comment: Antes do primeiro `if (isset(`, coloque isso numa linha acima: `print_r($_FILES); exit;`. Inclua o resultado desse teste na pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teu código está bem confuso, e ainda você usou `$_POST["imagem-produto"]` e `$_FILES['imagem-produto']` ao mesmo tempo, não tem sentido o mesmo nome em dois tipo de variáveis, no site tem vários exemplos de download simples, na documentação do PHP também, uso como está, aprenda o que cada variável [**superglobal**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) significa.

Outro problema é que aqui você usou nomes diferentes:

```
$arquivoTMP = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
$nomeF = $_FILES["imagem-produto"]["name"];
```

Um esta `$_FILES['arquivo']` e outro `$_FILES["imagem-produto"]`, não adianta sair digitando aleatoriamente ou copiar exemplos de código sem saber o que esta fazendo, não entenda como uma critica negativa e sim positiva, aprenda usar as variáveis, faça algo como:

```
if (isset($_FILES['imagem-produto']['name']) && $_FILES['imagem-produto']['error'] == 0) {
    $arquivo = $_FILES['imagem-produto'];

    if ($arquivo['size'] < $tamanhoMax) {
        $arquivoTMP = $arquivo['tmp_name'];
        $nomeF = $arquivo["name"];
```

Além de reduzir o código você evita de ser confundir com as "keys".

Seu problema foi praticamente o mesmo que o desta pergunta [Formulário não executa script PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170817/3635), um série de "erros de digitação", por não saber bem o que estava fazendo, talvez copiado código de algum lugar, recomendo que faça uso das variaveis para reduzir código e aprenda primeiro como realmente as coisas funcionam, a documentação esta ae pra isto, estes links devem lhe ajudar:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.files.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.php

### Antes de tudo

Verifique se a sua pasta tem permissão de escrita `imagens_produtos`

### Código revisado

Eu refiz todo seu código, reorganizei e acredito que agora funcione.

> **Nota:** eu troquei a [**sintaxe alternativa**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) pela normal, isso porque a sintaxe alternativa é mais incomum de ser usada geralmente as pessoas usam apenas em pequenas ifs e não em códigos php extensos, ao meu ver ela seria melhor empregada aonde temos muito HTML e pouco PHP, por exemplo templates, algo assim parece melhor usado
>
> ```
> <?php if ($a == 5): ?>
> A é igual a 5
> <?php endif; ?>
> ```

Código completo:

```
<?php

$tamanhoMax = 1024 * 1024; # 1MB

if (isset($_FILES['imagem-produto']['name'])) {
    $arquivo = $_FILES['imagem-produto']; //Sua variavel

    if ($arquivo['error'] != 0) {
        switch ($code) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                $message = "O upload excedeu a configuração do upload_max_filesize no php.ini";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $message = "O upload excedeu o MAX_FILE_SIZE";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                $message = "O upload foi feito parcialmente";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $message = "Não foi selecionado um arquivo";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                $message = "Pasta temporaria não encontrada";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                $message = "Erro na escrita do disco";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                $message = "Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo";
                break;

            default:
                $message = "Erro desconhecido";
        }

        echo '<p class="alert error">', $message,'</p>';
    } else if ($arquivo['size'] < $tamanhoMax) {
        $arquivoTMP = $arquivo['tmp_name'];
        $nomeF = $arquivo["name"];

        //Seleciona extensão
        $extensaoF = pathinfo($nomeF, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        //Converte a extensão para minúsculo
        $extensaoF =  strtolower($extensaoF);

        //Somente imagens .jpg;.jpeg;.png
        if (strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.png', $extensaoF)) {

            //nome único para a imagem
            //Evita nomes com acentos ou caracteres alfanuméricos
            $novoNomeF = uniqid(time()).$extensaoF;

            //Concatena a pasta com o nome
            $destino = 'imagens_produtos/' . $novoNomeF;

            if (@move_uploaded_file($arquivoTMP, $destino)) {
                echo '<p class="alert success">Sua foto foi cadastrada com sucesso.</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p class="alert error">Erro ao salvar arquivo, aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p class="alert error">Só aceitamos arquivos com as extensões <span>.jpg</span>, <span>.png</span> ou <span>.jpeg</span> .</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p class="alert error">O arquivo de imagem ultrapassa o limite de peso. <span>(0.5MB)</span></p>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p class="alert error">Você não enviou nenhum arquivo.</p>';
}
```

E o formulário deve ficar assim:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="SUA PÁGINA PHP AQUI" method="POST">
    <label>Imagem do produto:</label>
    <input type="file" name="imagem-produto">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Coloque `enctype="multipart/form-data"` no form.

ou você esta tentando salvar em algum lugar sem permissão

Comment: já havia colocado, porém nem mesmo isso resolveu